# Urn without replacement i-th draw

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Place blue, white and red balls in a urn. Prove that the probability that the ith ball taken from the box without replacement is:

$$ P(X_i=r) = \frac{r}{r+b+w}$$

There is a way to prove this result mathematically? Its true for $P(X_2 =r)$ (using total probability law), but how can I prove and interpret this result?

Thanks!

Comment: For a more extensive discussion see Theorem 1 in section 5.3 of the 4th ed. of Kai Lai Chung's *Elementary Probability Theory*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may approach this in more than one way.

Let $n = r+b+w$.

**"Direct way":**

Each of the $n$ balls are equally likely to appear at the $i$-th position. There are $r$ red balls. So, you get
$$P(X_i = r) = \frac{r}{n}= \frac{r}{r+b+w}$$

**"Counting way:"**

A possible way of counting is as follows:

- There are $n!$ possible sequences to draw the $n$ balls without replacement.
- There are $\color{red}{r}$ options to fix $\color{red}{\mbox{one}}$ red ball for the $i$-th position.
- The remaining $n\color{red}{-1}$ balls can appear in $(n\color{red}{-1})!$ ways in the remaining positions.

All together:
$$P(X_i = r)=\frac{\color{red}{r} \cdot (n\color{red}{-1})!}{n!}= \frac{\color{red}{r}}{n} =  \frac{r}{r+b+w}$$

Comment: There isnt $(n-i)!$ possible sequences to draw i balls out of n? In the ith draw, I have n-i balls, why there is n balls equally likely to appear in ith position?

Comment: @Felipe: Maybe the following model helps: Imagine n playing cards (red, blue, and white ones). You shuffle them well. Now, you ask what is the probability of having a red one at the first position or what is the probability of having a red one at the $i$-th position. Obviously, this does not make a difference

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: One more question, the probability that $P(X_i=r)$ don't depend if $i \leq r$?

Comment: Exactly. What $i$ you choose, does not matter at all.